# Reading tokens from a file in python 3.x

Tags: python, python-3.x, input

Is there some way to read in information from a file by token regardless of the formatting?  For example, if I am trying to generate a ppm image from an input file and instead of 2 pixels being

```
255 0 0
0 0 255
```

it appears as

```
255
0 0
0
0 255
```

I'd like to read by token in this situation instead of by line in my loop but I can't find any built in methods regarding this.

Comment: What do you consider to be a token?

Comment: In this case I would consider 255 to be a token, or any other number for that matter.

Comment: So there isn't any built in way to read in these tokens one at a time or in groups of 3?

Comment: For some reason his answer prints out P3 400 200 255 255 0 0 instead of P3 400 200 255 255 255 255 0 0.  It skips a whole line from the file.

Answer (score 3):

You could always roll your own file iterator:

```
class file_tokens:
    def __init__(self, file):
        self.file = file
        self.line = []
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(self):
        while not len(self.line):
            self.line = self.file.readline()
            if not self.line:
                raise StopIteration
            self.line = self.line.split()
        return self.line.pop(0)
```

Then use like a normal file:

```
for token in file_tokens(open(infile)):
    print('Token: ' + token)
```

Comment: Do you think this is the best way to do this?

Comment: That depends on your purpose. If you will need to do this operation in several places throughout your code, then I think this method has a clear advantage over alternatives due to re-usability. If you only need to use it once, it's just as good to use a 2-level loop instead.

Comment: I will run through a for loop and then I need to start grabbing numbers in groups of 3 and appending them.

Comment: To avoid `iter() returned non-iterator of type` error you need to use `__next__` instread of `next` in Python 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), where the iter-able would be `line.split() for line in fin`:

```
>>> with open('temp.txt', 'r') as fin:
...      iter = chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in fin)
...      print(list(iter))
... 
['255', '0', '0', '0', '0', '255']
```

Comment: For some reason that causes it to skip over a line for no real reason, and then quit after just one line.

Comment: @user3448183 i cannot say what is the cause unless i see the code or file contents; for the example you included in the question above does work