# Reading Files in Python

Tags: python, list, ppm

I have a file that i want to use python to read it with.
The file is in the following format:

```
12
45
45
78
56
45
67
09
12
45
```

How can i append all these numbers into a list?!!
For example:

```
x = [12,45,45,78,56,45,67,09,12,45]
```

I am trying .strip() and .split() methods but i am missing something.

(This is a PPM file i am reading through and not using actual format because i just need to know the method)

Any help?!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22946241/using-python-3-x-to-properly-read-ppm-files

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
f = open(file_path, 'r')
x = [int(line) for line in f]
```